# Flask SQLAlchemy updated_on

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to create field `Datetime` which will update current date time when a row updated. I tried this:

```
updated_on = Column(DateTime, onupdate=db.func.now())
```

and this:

```
updated_on = Column(DateTime, server_onupdate=db.func.now())
```

But a field is update only when I add a new row and no changes after update this row.
upd:

```
class UserLog(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    state = Column(String(25))
    created_on = Column(DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())
    updated_on = Column(DateTime, onupdate=datetime.utcnow)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [`server_onupdate`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.server_default) does not do anything server-side, and it's only there so that SQLAlchemy knows the server is 'supposed to' generate a value upon update. It's really misleading. You have to manually configure your database to generate the value upon update. SQLAlchemy doesn't do it for you.

So use `onupdate`. `onupdate=datetime.utcnow`. Don't forget to import `datetime`.

Comment: Anyway `onupdate=datetime.utcnow` doesn't work. There is no update in this field when row changed.

Comment: Well something isn't right. `onupdate=db.func.now()` should also work. Can you show more code?

Comment: Add model definition